# How to change list name based on method parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

So I have multiple lists and based on the input to method parameter I want to change which list we will be looking into.

```
public int GetGrowthTime(string crop) //get the growth time of matching crop from list
    {
        Debug.Log($"{crop}Data");  //wheatData
        Debug.Log("type of " + ($"{crop}Data".GetType()));  //System.String
        return ($"{crop}Data"[0]);     //119
    }
```

I have written the outputs on the right as comments, unfortunately I can't take {crop}Data out of "" and I don't know any other way to do this. The output of return should've been 60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a good opportunity to use a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-8.0), which is a generic collection of unique keys and associated values. In your specific case, you might have a Dictionary with a `string` key and a `List<int>` value:

```cs
// The key will be the crop name, and the value is the list of growth times
Dictionary<string, List<int>> cropGrowthTimes = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

// At some point, you'll populate the Dictionary - maybe in your Start or Awake?
// [...]

public int GetGrowthTime(string crop)
{
    // Now we can directly retrieve the list we want using the supplied crop
    return cropGrowthTimes[crop][0];
}
```

Comment: I will add that it's returning 119 because $"{crop}Data"[0] accesses the fist char of the string $"{crop}Data" --evaluated to "wheatData" -- which is 'w' and has an ascii value of 119. But yeah a dict is the way to implement this

Comment: That's a good assessment! Yes, the index-based access of characters certainly added to OP's confusion here, since they ended up getting back a value but from a completely wrong place.